# Chaining Spring CookieLocaleResolver and AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I want to resolve the user's locale first by detecting a cookie, and if there isn't one then by the accept-language header. Spring seems to only want to accept a single `LocaleResolver`.

Interestingly, the spring docs for [`CookieLocaleResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/CookieLocaleResolver.html) state

> LocaleResolver implementation that uses a cookie sent back to the user
>   in case of a custom setting, with a fallback to the specified default
>   locale or the request's accept-header locale.

but this doesn't actually seem to be the case; testing shows it doesn't work and a quick look at the source shows it only gets the default if there is no cookie.

Is the only solution to write my own `LocaleResolver` implementation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like `CookieLocaleResolver` does exactly what you want as long as you don't set its `defaultLocale`.

If you want something different (for example, fallback to `defaultLocale` when neither cookie nor `Accept` header was found), you can override its `determineDefaultLocale()` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Maybe I just misunderstood the docs, it could be a little clearer.

Answer (score 9):

Example cookie locale resolver that fallback first to `Accept-Language` header and only then to `defaultLocale`:

```
public class CookieThenAcceptHeaderLocaleResolver extends CookieLocaleResolver {

    @Override
    protected Locale determineDefaultLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String acceptLanguage = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
        if (acceptLanguage == null || acceptLanguage.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return super.determineDefaultLocale(request);
        }
        return request.getLocale();
    }
}
```